# SQL Check constraint on numerous columns

Tags: sql, check-constraints

I am new to SQL and trying to add a check constraint which has numerous check.
(It's a theatre company and trying to add a check to the 'SeatNumber' to make sure only correct seats are allocated based on the location (i.e stalls, cirlce) and which theatre (theatre 1,2 or 3).

I have included below my attempt on the creation of the 'Seats' table with the constraints for the CHECK - I receive an error stating 'TheatreID' references another column, table 'Seats'.

```
SeatID CHAR(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Seats PRIMARY KEY,
SeatLocation VARCHAR(10)NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_Seats_SeatLocation CHECK(SeatLocation = 'Stalls'or SeatLocation= 'Back Stall' or SeatLocation='Upper Stalls' or SeatLocation= 'Circle'),
SeatNumber CHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
TheatreID CHAR(5) CONSTRAINT FK_Seats_Theatre FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Theatre(TheatreID)
CONSTRAINT CHK_Seats_SeatNumber_SeatLocation_TheatreID CHECK ((SeatNumber <251 and SeatLocation = 'Stalls' and TheatreID = 1)
OR (SeatNumber BETWEEN 251 AND 500 AND SeatLocation = 'Back Stall' and TheatreID = 1)
OR (SeatNumber <30 and SeatLocation = 'Stalls' and TheatreID = 2)
OR(SeatNumber BETWEEN 31 AND 60 AND SeatLocation = 'Upper stalls' and TheatreID = 2)
OR (SeatNumber <60 AND SeatLocation = 'Stalls' and TheatreID = 3)
OR (SeatNumber BETWEEN 61 AND 160 AND SeatLocation = 'Upper stalls' and TheatreID = 3))
);

GO
```

Comment: You would need to add it as a table level constraint not a column level constraint (by adding a comma after `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Theatre(TheatreID),`) but this does seem to be doing a lot of work!

Comment: Probably `SeatLocation` shouldn't be in that table at all. You should have another table with SeatLocation mappings to seat number ranges

Comment: This is a lot of validation, probably would make more sense to validate the data before inserting and raise an appropriate error if necessary, as soon as your seats or locations etc change you'll have to re-create the constraint instead of simply amending data in a table.

Comment: Great Thank you